# Python requests_html: BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly

Tags: python, python-requests-html

I'm trying to use the Python requests_html library to load content from a specific website. I do this in a method `_get_content()`:

```py
def _get_content(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(url)
    response.html.render()
    return response.html.html
```

On my own box I'm able to run this and it works as expected, but when I send it to a remote hosting server which runs the code in Docker, it generates this error:

Stack Trace:

```
File "/home/container/bot.py", line 33, in _get_content
    response.html.render()
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 730, in browser
    self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests_html.py", line 714, in browser
    self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 307, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 168, in launch
    self.browserWSEndpoint = get_ws_endpoint(self.url)
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/container/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyppeteer/launcher.py", line 227, in get_ws_endpoint
    raise BrowserError('Browser closed unexpectedly:\n')
pyppeteer.errors.BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:
```

I looked around in forums for a bit and it seems that the problem has something to do with Chromium not being  completely installed in the remote environment. However, I do not have access to environment in which the code is running (only access is to the files with my code), and so cannot install Chromium manually myself.

Any tips on what I could do would be greatly appreciated.